# constructing a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: java

I am trying to construct a skew symmetric matrix. I can print the negatives but I am unable to print the diagonal to be 0. Where am I incorrect logically?

```
public void SkewSymmetric() {


    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < matrix.length; i++) {
            matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(BOUND);

        }
    }

    for (int i = 9; i < matrix.length; ++j) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            matrix[j][j] = -matrix[i][i];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rolled back as the answers are invalidated otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop in the second block needs to run from i + 1.

Otherwise the trace will be, in general, non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting all the values in the matrix to 0 and then trying over-write the non-diagonal values.
Instead set only the primary diagonal values to 0.

As pointed out by Jean, your loop values are incorrect.
For the first row random numbers are generated from column 1 to n
For the second row random numbers are generated from column 2 to n and so on.

Try this,

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
                if(i==j){
                 matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt();

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = -matrix[j][i];

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `for (int j = i; j < matrix.length; j++)`: when `j == i` at the first iteration, it erases the 0 that have been previsouly set.

Therefore you need to change it to `for (int j = i+1; j < matrix.length; j++)`